# Should I sign my emails as "Dr" or "PhD" when looking for an apartment?

Tags: housing, switzerland

I'm moving to Zurich in a couple of months. I'm wondering if I should sign my emails with "Dr" or "PhD" (I have one) when I inquire for apartments?

I would never do this in my own country as I find it incredibly pompous (and landlords would too). However, I've been advised by my future supervisor to give her as a reference and clearly indicate that she is "Dr XXX". Apparently doctorates are much more respected in Germanic countries than where I come from. So would it be appropriate to sign my emails as "Dr. XXX" or "XXX, PhD", to increase my chances? Or would this act as a deterrent?

Comment: Would probably depend on type of apartment/landlord, but generally Dr. is probably better. Phd makes it clear the degree is not from Switzerland/Germany.

Comment: @TomasBy Thanks. But my question is, should I put "Dr" at all or not?

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood the last sentence. It seems a bit silly, but if your supervisor thinks it would help, then why not.

Comment: In Germany, it would make a difference as to the country, and in some cases even the university, where the degree was awarded.  The use of "Dr" is permitted for some but not others.  I don't know if Switzerland is the same, though.

Comment: If the landlord is a snob and it's hard to get approved for the apartment you want, then my guess is, either title would impress, and if the landlord wants to know more, s/he'll ask.  But the safest thing would be to email the question to your supervisor.